# start firebase cloud messaging service as foreground service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which i need to send notification with data
im using the fcm service but on 80% of the installed devices the system kill my service and dont allow me to send data notifications so i want to make the fcm work as a foreground service i tried this but it didnt work

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
private static final int ID_SERVICE = 101;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String channelId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? createNotificationChannel(notificationManager) : "";
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(ID_SERVICE, notification);

}
```

is there any way to solve that problem or to make the fcm work in background

Comment: On Android, it doesn't matter if Android kills your app.  A message that gets delivered to an Android app first goes through Play services on the device, which never gets killed.  Play services then delivers the message to your app, and the app should wake to receive it.  So, I'm not understanding the problem you're trying to solve by making the service a foreground service.

Comment: on phones like xiaomi and huawei your app services get killed by the os when the app go to background and you cant receive messages. this is a cummon problem  https://dontkillmyapp.com

Comment: Yeah, all modern Android devices do that.  The app process should be launched again when the service is invoked by Play services, which is a different, privileged app process and never gets killed.  App processes with foreground services can still get killed by Android, though, so it's not really a solution.  (Imagine if **every** app tried to start a foreground service - how would they all stay alive and in memory?)

Comment: The devices you're talking about do have the Google Play Store installed, right?  Because FCM won't work without it.  That's how Play services also gets installed, which is required for FCM to even work at all on Android.

Comment: yes it has google play store installed   . i dont know what to do to resolve that problem